# Get json on http protocol by recv() system call in C?

Tags: json, sockets, http

I'm receiving invalid characters on try to receiving JSON by http protocol in C.
When I send

`GET /<query> http/1.1\r\nHost:<host>\r\n\r\n`

then the result displays as follow:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sun, 07 Dec 2014 13:14:29 GMT
Content-Length: 11410

�
```

I don't know why I don't receiving JSON? However, in browser's address bar I type the same query & I received the json as well.

**[UPDATE # 1]**

I found it useful to work on built-in library, as the error is related to `network byte compressions` so I used Qt's library `QNetworkManager` specifically to done this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt's `QNetworkManager` is best for this purpose, as it do all the intricate stuff itself & provide elegant interface to user.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a HTTP library or make yourself comfortable with the HTTP protocol and implement it properly.

> Content-Encoding: gzip

At least this line means trouble for your simple parsing. But interestingly, based on your request the server should not sent this line if a non-compressed version is available. This means not only your code is buggy, but that the server might be buggy too (it actually assume that you understand any compressions because you did not say different).

> GET / http/1.1\r\nHost:\r\n\r\n

And your request is wrong too. It must be `HTTP/1.1` instead of `http/1.1`.  And it must contain a proper host header.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the response is compressed in gzip. I don't want to use any library. Can you tell me how can I read this compressed data and decompress it in this situation?

Comment: It would be too much effort too describe everything just because you don't want to use existing libraries. Get a library, read the source code and re-implement all the stuff you need itself. Or read the necessary documentation. This is not an easy task and you will learn a lot while implementing it, but probably end up with something slower and less compatible.